# After adding root volume CPU utilization is continously full

Tags: cpu, fdisk

My `fdisk /dev/root` occupies full space without any reason.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "adding root volume"?

Comment: What did you try to do with `/dev/root`, and why do you have this file at all (it's not a normal part of Ubuntu)? Please write the exact commands you have run for this process to start using CPU. Nobody can help you by guessing what happened.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.